# limiting the frequency a neighbor is chosen in nearest neighbor algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, matching, nearest-neighbor, propensity-score-matching

I have a `pandas DataFrame` with propensity scores for treated (=1) and untreated (0) subjects. For each treated subject, I want to find the closest propensity score of now untreated subject. This is my current approach:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

treated = df[df[treatment_col]==1]
untreated = df[df[treatment_col]==0]
pscore_treated = treated[[matching_col]]
pscore_untreated = untreated[[matching_col]]
knn = NearestNeighbors(
    n_neighbors=1,
    n_jobs=-1,
)
knn.fit(pscore_untreated)
distances, indices = knn.kneighbors(pscore_treated)
```

The problem is, that some of the untreated subjects are matched very often. I'd like to limit the time each subject can be matched. I also tried coding the matching algorithm myself, which would be more flexible but ended up to be super slow:

```
max_freq_matches = 5
for i in treatment_indices:
    distances = np.abs(propensity_scores[i] - propensity_scores[control_indices])
    closest_index = control_indices[np.argmin(distances)]
    matched_pairs.append((i, closest_index))
    controls_matched = [i for _,i in matched_pairs]
    if sum([1 if i == mode(controls_matched) else 0 for i in test]) >= max_freq_matches:
         control_indices = np.delete(control_indices, np.where(control_indices == mode(test)), axis=0)
```

Is there a more clever way to do that?

Comment: In the R package `MatchIt` this is just a parameter called `reuse.max`. Consider using a Python interface to R to take advantage of this and other features.